# Watson assistant algorithm used

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Can anyone tell me what algorithm is used to classify intents and understand entities in Watson assistant? Have they published any papers or articles regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to IBM Developer Answers:

"Intents are classified using an SVM, with some pre training by IBM. entities use a fuzzy matching algorithm."
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/387916/watson-conversation-algorithm/

Support Vector Machine (SVM) is a supervised machine learning algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they published this [paper](http://johncreid.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/The-Era-of-Cognitive-Systems-An-Inside-Look-at-IBM-Watson-and-How-it-Works_.pdf) explaining in a manner how the Watson Work, and for more information you should learn about Cognitive Systems, but in advance it's not just one algorithm used, but many approaches that combined are capable of getting the desired result.

Another material you should learn if this is your interest is the computer science area "Information Retrieval", in which many subjects are used to comprehend what the user wants and give the needed information. The book Modern Information Retrieval is a good start point.

Comment: Thank you sir for the information i will go through it

Comment: @JACK that paper is on the original Watson, not related to Watson Assistant.